# how can send data every 500ms and received data by using UDP for android studio

Tags: android, udp

how can send data every 500ms and received data by using UDP for android studio

I mean i need send data for example "DATA"   every 500ms to any server and Received feedback for this server and display this data in textview

I need this for reading temperature from server and update data in the server
for example run motor or any thing

thank you for All

Answer (score 0):

you will used services for background process and hit api into services and repeat services using alarm trigger.
i mean alarm based intent services used which perform task in background.

Comment: tell me your email id?

Comment: eng.hasanhadi@gmail.com